# amdgpu-pro not playing videos

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

Ubuntu 18.04 and Radeon RX550. When running amdgpu would get irregularly blank or one colour screen and then the system would freeze. Upgraded to amdgpu-pro, screen no longer freezes but it does occasionally flicker and VLC or Videos does not play movies. I get streaming videos OK.
Any help greatly appreciated 
Michael